# How to disable proxy setup script on Windows 10 using a script?

Tags: windows, proxy, windows-registry

In Edge, settings> system > Open your computer's proxy settings

I have this

[image]

I need to untoggle the "Use setup script", using a script, since there is some background process I can't control that keeps toggling this back on.

I want a script that runs every 5 sec and toggles this off.

---

Here is what I have based on many searches, and that doesn't work:

basic, doesn't do anything

```
@ECHO OFF

REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

also doesn't do anything

Adding

```
Shell.run "ms-settings:network-proxy"

WScript.Sleep 1000

Shell.Run "taskkill /f /im SystemSettings.exe", , True
```

also doesn't do anything.

---

I need to toggle-off the above setting.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A batch command to remove the proxy is:

```
netsh winhttp reset proxy
```

This command needs to be run as Administrator.

Reference:
[Configure device proxy and Internet connectivity settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/configure-proxy-internet?view=o365-worldwide).

---

As the above didn't help the poster, I traced the Settings app and
found that this setting is found under the registry key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`.

The value name is `AutoConfigURL`. Setting it to empty
has undone the setting of "Use setup script" in the Settings app.

Using a batch command that is run as Administrator:

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v AutoConfigURL /t REG_SZ /f
```

Comment: When running this as administrator (or not) the state of the toggle remains the same.

Comment: After this command, the proxy is not supposed to exist any more.

Comment: Looking at the same settings window as in the question, the toggle is still on after running this.

Comment: I traced through and found it. See above.

Comment: Thanks :) Please correct me if I'm wrong, isn't this exactly what I posted in the question? `REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f`

Comment: You are modifying `ProxyEnable` ("Use a proxy server"), while I do `AutoConfigURL` ("Use setup script").

Comment: I suppose I don't understand what line I need to write instead. Can you please show it?

Comment: I added the command to the answer. Specifying no value in the command means that it's set to empty.

Comment: Gave it a while to see it is stable, it works! Thank you, you saved me a lot of hair

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in a batch file. I'm using Windows 10:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v AutoConfigURL /t REG_SZ /d "" /f
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a bit old now, but I had this situation come up for myself recently and ended up making this PowerShell script which toggles both switches back off. Note with this setup the setup script field itself is not cleared, the switch for it is simply toggled off, which I believe is more specific to what is being asked for (preserving the script field for later in case it's needed again in my case).

Since, like the described situation, the field will periodically be switched back on for me, I figured there was also no point in clearing the setup script field anyways. I just needed the toggle switched off easier, but not all the time. As such, I've only found myself running it manually when needed, but running this on the desired schedule should suffice too.

```
$key = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections'
$data = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name DefaultConnectionSettings).DefaultConnectionSettings
$data[8] = 1
Set-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name DefaultConnectionSettings -Value $data
```

Similar to some of the other scripts and the original attempted solution, this targets the registry key where the toggles are set. It sets the 9th bit of that key to 1 which corresponds to off for both proxy switch settings.